# How can I retrieve elements and properties from the given JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

How can I access each of the properties in the given JSON?

I would also like to filter the particular objects based on their IDs. How to do that using array.filter method in javascript?

```
{
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "abcd",
            "fields": {
                "term": [
                    "xyz"
                ],
                "groupId": 888,
                "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
                "url_c": [
                    "https://www.google.com"
                ],
                "pID": [
                    "1800"
                ],
                "location": [
                    "mumbai"
                ],
                "url_location": [
                    "https://www.mumbai.com/"
                ]
            },
            "createdTime": "2021-05-12T10:18:33.000Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently I'm trying to do this:

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://apiurl//"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setInfo(data.records);
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

let resultInfo = info.filter((x) => x.groupId == gid);
console.log(resultInfo[0].fields.groupId);
```

But it shows error

Comment: Off-topic: since fetch is async, response might come after component is unmounted. You need to make sure not to call `setInfo` in this case. Consider using https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useAsync.md, it handles everything under the hood.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about this question as What is actually gid? Most probably you are doing it right except few things that needs to be change which can be recognized once we have all the information. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing your `info` as an empty object. So your code is trying to run `filter` on an object which will return an error. Also in your filter check is wrong based on the json example you shared

You should change

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState({});

let resultInfo = info.filter((x) => x.groupId == gid);
```

to

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);

let resultInfo = info.filter((x) => x.fields.groupId == gid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's asynchronous either define things in .then() method or you can simply use asyn await to let things work for you.

Something like

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://apiurl//"
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
    if(data && data.records){
        console.log(data);
        const records = data.records.filter((x) => x.fields.groupId == gid);
        setInfo(records);
    // if you will log info here most probably it might log default value so check in your render method for the latest value
     }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

Make sure gid is same as your groupId. For surity you can just pass static number just to test.
Now try to access info in your render method like:

```
return 
<div>
{JSON.stringify(info)}
</div>
```

Comment: This works but I get this error on my console: **Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.**

Comment: @Aishwariya Since you are calling an asynchronous function unmount you must abort that function in the cleanup method of useEffect. You can check various option that can be done to abort a fetch request such as AbortController in React etc. For this you can ask another question or check solutions. Please mark it as answer if your task is done it will help others to find useful answers . Thanks